# How to mount Kubernetes NFS share from external computer?

Tags: kubernetes, nfs

I'm able to create an NFS server using Docker, then mount it from an external computer on the network.  My laptop for example.

Docker example:

```
docker run -itd --privileged \
  --restart unless-stopped \
  -e SHARED_DIRECTORY=/data \
  -v /home/user/nfstest/data:/data \
  -p 2049:2049 \
  itsthenetwork/nfs-server-alpine
```

I **am** to mount the above server onto a local machine using

```
sudo mount -v 192.168.60.80:/ nfs
```

From my local laptop, I always get permission errors when trying to mount an NFS share that is hosted by Kubernetes.  Can someone please explain why I may be getting permission errors not allowing me to mount the NFS share when creating the NFS server with Kubernetes?

As an example, I create my persistent volume:

```
piVersion: v1                                                                                                                     [0/1864]
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 80Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: local-nfs-storage
  local:
    path: "/home/rancher/nexus-data"
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - kubenode-02
```

Then create the persistent volume claim:

```
apiVersion: v1                                                                                                                     [0/1865]
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: nfs-pvc
spec:
  storageClassName: local-nfs-storage
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 80Gi
```

Last, I create the NFS server deployment.  I use the external IP service (externalIPs) so that I can connect to the pod from anywhere outside of my Kubernetes network.  I can Nmap the ports from my laptop and see that they are open.

```
---                                                                                                                                                                   
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nfs-service
spec:
  selector:
    role: nfs
  ports:
    # Open the ports required by the NFS server
    # Port 2049 for TCP
    - name: tcp-2049
      targetPort: 2049
      port: 2049
      protocol: TCP
    # Port 111 for UDP
    - name: udp-111
      targetPort: 111
      port: 111
      protocol: UDP
  # Use host network with external IP service
  externalIPs:
    - 192.168.60.42

---                                                                                 
apiVersion: apps/v1                                                                 
kind: Deployment                                                                    
metadata:                                                                           
  name: nfs-server                                                                  
spec:                                                                               
  replicas: 1                                                                       
  selector:                                                                         
    matchLabels:                                                                    
      role: nfs                                                                     
  template:                                                                         
    metadata:                                                                       
      name: nfs-server                                                              
      labels:                                                                       
        role: nfs                                                                   
    spec:                                                                           
      volumes:                                                                      
        - name: nfs-pv-storage                                                      
          persistentVolumeClaim:                                                    
            claimName: nfs-pvc                                                      
      securityContext:                                                              
        fsGroup: 1000                                                               
      containers:                                                                   
        - name: nfs-server-container                                                
          image: itsthenetwork/nfs-server-alpine                                    
          securityContext:                                                          
            privileged: true                                                        
          env:                                                                      
            # Pass the path to share data                                           
            - name: SHARED_DIRECTORY                                                
              value: "/exports"                                                     
          volumeMounts:                                                             
            - mountPath: "/exports"                                                 
              name: nfs-pv-storage
```

I have tried playing with Pod Security policies such as fsGroup, runAsUser, and runAsGroup.  I have played with different permissions for the local folder I am mounting the NFS share onto.  I have also tried different options for /etc/exports within the NFS pod.  No matter what, I get a permission denied when trying to mount the NFS share to a local computer.

I **AM** able to mount the Kubernetes NFS share from within a separate Kubernetes Pod.

Is there something I do not understand about how the Kubernetes network handles external traffic?

Comment: Which Kubernetes version are you using? Did you consider using [`nfs` volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#nfs)?

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding, you want to create a NFS server on Kubernetes cluster, so nfs volume type is not related. My questions -  is the external IP that you are using in the service definition routing traffic to node / nodes of your cluster? How many nodes do you have? Which Kubernetes solution did you use to setup your cluster - kubeadm? Could you share logs of the pod from the nfs-server deployment? Which Kubernetes version are you using? Did you try [this similar solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/987935/nfs-server-on-a-kubernetes-node)?

Comment: Sorry I hadn't replied sooner.  The external IP I'm using is the actual Kubernetes node that I'm creating the pod on.  I have 3 nodes total.  I've tried 1 replica and multiple replicas.  I've also used nodeSelector to make sure my pod stays on the same node as the external IP address.  Instead of Kubeadm, I'm using K3s on K3os.  I can share logs some time after work.  It's running on my home lab.

Comment: I'm specifically using version v0.21.5-k3s2r1 @ https://github.com/rancher/k3os/releases.  I actually first built this out using the link you provided.  If I create the example of the pod using the NFS server, I can connect.  I just have problems when I try and connect to the NFS server's external IP address from an external machine, not using Kubernetes.

Comment: Could you [create an example NGINX deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-stateless-application-deployment/#creating-and-exploring-an-nginx-deployment) and create a similar service using `externalIPs` and check if it is working from laptop? `From my local laptop, I always get permission errors when trying to mount an NFS share that is hosted by Kubernetes.` -> could you share exact error message? Please also share logs from a pod from the nfs-server deployment.